# WPF DataGrid takes long time to display data after ItemSource is updated

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

I tried to load the datagrid based on the selection of two combo boxes. When a combo box item selected it updates the SelectedAccounts property which is set as ItemSource for datagrid binding. I checked that ItemSource is updated quickly but WPF DataGrid takes long time to display data(~ 2500 rows). Please suggest me to improve loading performance.

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgSelecteAccounts" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedAccounts}" SelectionMode="Extended" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Margin="0,25,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="600">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" SortDirection="Ascending" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="300" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>



   <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="890" Height="28" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top">
         <Label Content="As of Date:" Foreground="Black"/>
         <ComboBox Width="135" ItemsSource="{Binding AsOfDates}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPeriod, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" util:CancellableSelectionBehavior.SelectionChangeAllowedChecker="{Binding FilterChangedCheck}"/>
         <Label Content="{Binding SelectedCategory.Name}" ContentStringFormat=" {0}:" Foreground="Black" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
         <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AumCategoryValues}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategoryValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Width="135" util:CancellableSelectionBehavior.SelectionChangeAllowedChecker="{Binding FilterChangedCheck}" />
   </StackPanel>


    private ObservableCollection<FirmAumAccount> selectedAccounts;
    public ObservableCollection<FirmAumAccount> SelectedAccounts
    {
        get { return selectedAccounts; }
        set
        {
            selectedAccounts = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedAccounts");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the existing problem with WPF data grid. When number of rows increases, its performance goes down. ll keep checking ur post, if there is any solution available for the same.

Comment: Enable virtualization

Comment: @devhedgehog  Added EnableRowVirtualization="True". But Could not see the difference.

Comment: Put your DataGrid in a Grid or any fix sized panel and enable virtualization. If inside panels like ScrollPanel (ScrollViewer) or StackPanel the DataGrid wont virtualize.